# Why "langage de programmation" and not "langue de programmation"?

Tags: choix-de-mot

The French nouns *langue* and *langage* are both translated into English as "language." *Langue* normally means a specific language:

> La langue française

whereas *langage* means either the phenomenon of language in general, or specific styles of utterances, as we can see by the following two examples.

> Le langage, c'est ce qui sépare les êtres humains des bêtes.
>
> Parle plus poliment, s'il te plaît ; je n'aime pas ton langage.

However, the English phrase "programming language" seems often to be translated by *langage de programmation*, whereas in accordance with the examples I gave above, *langue* would make more sense. Have I understood the meaning of these two words badly or incompletely, or is there some other explanation?

Comment: It's likely a case of false friends, the same way we say "un téléphone portable" rather than "un téléphone portatif." The English term sounds French-like, so it's mistranslated. No proof of that, however.

Comment: I'd think it may be a distinction between 'real' languages (btw, isn't tongues used also, as in 'mother tongue', in English?) and made up languages, like programming languages.

Comment: @jv42 Not so much real vs. made up, as coded vs. natural (a subtle, but real, distinction — birdsong is a *langage* while Esperanto is a *langue*).

Comment: I am with @Gilles on this: assuming by "natural vs. coded", he means "spoken-by-humans vs. everything else". There is also a nuance of completeness: "langues" are expected to cover the full spectrum of human communication needs, whereas "languages" only cover a subset (logic, technical jargon etc.). "Langue des signes" is another interesting example...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Les plus anciennes occurrences de « langage de programmation » sur [Google Books](http://www.google.fr/search?tbo=p&tbm=bks&q=%22langage+de+programmation%22&tbs=,cdr:1,cd_max:31%20d%C3%A9c.%201960&num=10) sont :

- Des articles scientifiques d'informatique à partir de 1957 :

  > Etude des systèmes de codage et étude du système Fortran comme langage de programmation. [[Bulletin analytique: Volume 20, Part 1, Issues 40744-60861](http://books.google.com/books?id=Nk_QAAAAMAAJ&q=%22langage+de+programmation%22&dq=%22langage+de+programmation%22&hl=en&ei=e7BSTuX6HeqK4gSIvYWoBw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2&ved=0CDcQ6AEwATgK)]
  >   Ainsi définie, l'opération symbolisée permet de conserver un langage de programmation aussi proche que possible du langage mathématique habituel à l'utilisateur. [[Revue française de traitement de l'information, 1958](http://books.google.fr/books?id=NBa7AAAAIAAJ&q=%22langage+de+programmation%22&dq=%22langage+de+programmation%22&hl=fr&ei=XLFSTo24Kojk4QSltOXyBw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3&ved=0CEAQ6AEwAg)]
- [une annonce pour Hatier (?)](http://books.google.com/books?id=emAszDCs4KAC&q=%22langage+de+programmation%22&dq=%22langage+de+programmation%22&hl=en&ei=e7BSTuX6HeqK4gSIvYWoBw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=8&ved=0CE4Q6AEwBzgK).

  > Aujourd'hui, Hatier dispose de son propre langage de programmation, de ;s méthodes de production et d'un vier de 80 auteurs capables de ïaliser des logiciels.

À l'époque, l'innovation dans le domaine se faisait surtout en langue anglaise, il était donc naturelle de transposer au plus près « *programming language* ». Quant à un hypothétique « langue de programmation », on n'en trouve aucune trace en France. Par contre, en cherchant [`"langue de programmation"` sur Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22langue+de+programmation%22#q=%22langue+de+programmation%22&fp=4ce734a7da4ce7e2), on tombe sur de nombreuses occurrences canadiennes, le terme semble admis en français québecois (ce que j'ignorais jusqu'à maintenant).

Alors, anglicisme en France et construction plus conforme au génie de la langue au Québec ? Je n'ai pas l'impression.

D'abord, la distinction entre *langage* et *langue* a évolué au fil du temps, et en particulier l'utilisation de *langue française* à l'exclusion que *langage français*, remonte au XIX<sup>e</sup> siècle (Le *Dictionnaire de l'Académie française* ne la fait qu'à partir de sa 7<sup>e</sup> édition en 1878).

Ensuite et surtout, le mot [langage](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/langage) peut aussi désigner un **système de communication codé**, par opposition à la langue qui est un système d'expression direct. Ce sens remonte à bien longtemps ; même avant la [Pascaline](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascaline), on parlait de *langage d'oiseaux*. La 9<sup>e</sup> édition du *Dictionnaire de l'Académie* (1932) dit ceci du mot *langage* :

> Il désigne plus particulièrement la Manière de s'exprimer, soit par rapport aux mots qu'on emploie, soit par rapport au sens. *Langage figuré, allégorique, mystique, poétique, orné, affecté, fleuri, pompeux.* [...] Il se dit, par extension, des Cris, du chant, etc., dont les animaux se servent pour se faire entendre. *Les oiseaux ont une sorte de langage. Le langage des bêtes.* Il se dit encore, figurément, de Tout ce qui sert à exprimer des idées et des sensations. *Langage du geste, des yeux. Le langage symbolique des fleurs. La pantomime est un langage muet. Le langage des signes. On a composé, pour les sourds-muets, un langage au moyen de divers mouvements de la main et des doigts.*

Ou, pour reprendre les définitions proposées par le [*Trésor de la langue française*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/langage) :

> II.A.1. Usage particulier d'une langue, manière de parler. [...]
>   *En particulier.* Ensemble des règles de la grammaire, des règles concernant le lexique d'une langue donnée. [...]
>   *Langage diplomatique*, *langage administratif*, *langage mathématique*, *langage géométrique*, ...
>   2. Ensemble des moyens d'expression particuliers à un art, ou utilisés par un artiste pour créer une œuvre. *Langage chromatique, musical.*

Il est donc logique de parler du *langage de la programmation*. Ce qui est peut-être un peu moins direct, c'est de parler d'***un*** langage de programmation. C'est toutefois un usage qu'avaient déjà les mathématiciens.

> *[Leibniz] concevait la notion de langage formalisé, pure combinaison de signes dont seul importe l'enchaînement, de sorte qu'une machine serait capable de fournir tous les théorèmes, et que toutes les controverses se résoudraient par un simple calcul* (Bourbaki, Hist. math., 1960, p. 16). [cité par le [TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/langage), §II.B.2 : *langages artificiels*, établis en fonction d'axiomes, de règles d'écriture]

La forme *langage de programmation* me semble donc bien être d'un lignage tout à fait respectable en français (de France).

Comment: c'est vrai qu'en français on dirait "langage codé" et "langue" ferait tout de suite penser à quelque chose de parlé.

Comment: Gilles, je me suis permis d'éditer pour virer ton exemple daté de 1932: c'est une collection de numéros de revue, et l'année en question correspond au début du recueil. Si j'ai bien lu, la page que tu cites date de 1969.

Comment: @Gilles: comme tu le fais remarquer, la notion de langage formel (qui a éventuellement donné les langages de programmation moderne: en nom et en principe) est très ancienne et précède largement l'apparition du terme anglais. Un choix de traduction du à l'influence anglaise me parait beaucoup moins probable qu'un  choix motivé pour des raisons de vocabulaire.

Answer (score 4):

It is not *often* translated as "language". Rather, I have never heard any other translation in this context. I tend to believe that the term "programming language" was coined in English and that the French kept the "language" part without strictly translating it as "langue".

This peculiarity is actually very useful in French, since there is no ambiguity when you ask someone:

> Combien de langages connais-tu ? (Always computer-related)

or

> Combien de langues connais-tu ? (Always linguistic-related)

Comment: I do think it's been translated into *“language de programmation”*.

Answer (score 0):

> The french nouns langue and langage are both translated as "language" in English. Langue normally means a specific language:

A la pertinence des réponses apportées, on pourrait ajouter :

- langue : 17 muscles,
- langue : organisation de mots que l'on peut prononcer dans un dictionnaire, une grammaire, l'Histoire, les analyse de toutes sortes, la littérature, la philosophie, la métaphysique ou l'ontologie, le théâtre, les poèmes... qui construisent un humain au sein d'une société.
- langage : utilisation d'une langue, mais aussi toute forme d'expression intelligible, telle *le langage des oiseaux* dont même les humains étrangers à cette culture peuvent comprendre l'intention (cri d'alerte contre un prédateur, appel amoureux, bagarre entre mâles ..)

mais déjà une incohérence avec la sentence :

> Le langage, c'est ce qui sépare les êtres humains des bêtes.

à cela s'ajoute la collision poétique [des langues d’Ésope](http://ceciestuntest.over-blog.com/article-15282896.html) qui s'agitent en langage et révèlent la *duplicité* de ce dernier.

Si on utilise un aphorisme, un adage, un apophtegme, une formule, une maxime, une sentence, on se situe dans l'*objectivité* : je suis différent de l'oiseau, l'oiseau ne parle pas DONC c'est la différence entre humains et bêtes, voilà MA belle pensée.
... inutile de gloser sur l’anthropomorphisme latent, "comparaison n'est pas raison".
C'est une des difficultés du choix des exemples.

Le langage est commun a tout ce qui vit, à nous de le *décoder*.

En revanche, à la façon d'Ésope, si l'on utilise l'*expression poétique*, la *subjectivité* ou l'*intuition*, on se sert d'une expérience sensible [perceptible par éventuellement plusieurs sens] que l'on suit dans sa transformation en mots et en expression, et pour en maîtriser le choix, il faut s'arrêter : 
est-ce qu'au moment de la transformation/codification de la langue en langage cela va devenir :
- une transmission de connaissance, un partage d'une découverte dont on a conscience (notion de don),
- ou la communication d'un savoir qui m'isole sur un niveau prétendu supérieur, la manipulation des symboles pour asseoir un pouvoir ou de nos jours une publicité (notion de possession).

Utilisons l'arbre :

- la langue de la bouche (ou du bec) serait les racines, un lien à la terre, à la réalité sensible, en connexion avec l'excitation des neurones qu'elle doit traduire, elle est ainsi la base de l'architecture à développer, l'outil qui va réaliser le plan,
- la langue inconnue des anglophones serait le tronc et ses branches maîtresses, l'architecture (dans ce qu'elle a de visible lorsque le plan est réalisé), le support et les objets de la précédente. A maturité ils sont prêts pour tout usage,
- le langage est alors la ramée qui devient bruissante lorsque les souffles variés du vent l'anime.

En me servant de ce classeur mnémotechnique, j'ai voulu réduire les incertitudes (savoir s'il n'y avait pas d'exception, d'imprécision, une erreur de formulation, ..) avec les définitions proposées, je n'en perçois pas, ...  toute autre point de vue sera appréciée.

Pour l'informatique on pourrait éventuellement dire que :
- la bouche (dont le verbe est acte) serait l'architecture von Neumann 
[sans rapport avec la terre, certes, mais pilote des stimulations qui agitent la langue qui traduisent un plan.
 C'est là un des problèmes récurrents lorsque l'on prête, par anthropomorphisme, la vie à un artefact. L'exemple peut perdre de l'élégance, mais on peut aussi dire que la langue buccale est construite (son évolution est conduite) par l'architecture neuronale],

- le tronc, les microprocesseurs, car les circuits insensibles "incarnent" une langue "codée en dur" 

- et que  tout ce que les humains peuvent entendre, lire, traduire, interpréter est alors rattaché au langage, avec les risques d'utilisation relevés par Ésope dans le cette tour de Babel-Web (Homophonie : Babel-Oued, ville d'Algérie dont le nom est entré dans le langage familier)

J'ai bien conscience que la langue française peut être très difficile à appréhender, j'espère seulement que l'approche intuitive et le langage que je viens d'utiliser restent compréhensibles, qu'un éclairage différent élargisse la compréhension du mot langue et de ses dérivés.